# foreach in gridview columns yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have relations in main model

```
public function getItems(){
   return $this->hasOne(OrderItems::className(), ['order_id' => 'order_id']);
}
```

In Items `order_id` has many `order_items_id`. How could I get all `order_items_id` for `order_id` in one cell in column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation should be with `hasMany` and not `hasOne`

```
public function getItems(){
   return $this->hasOne(OrderItems::className(), ['order_id' => 'order_id']);
}
```

To solve your problem I'll try with raw sql, using GROUP_CONCAT:

```
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(order_items_id SEPARATOR ', ') FROM OrderItems";
$orderItemsIds = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryColumn();
```